# is ajax actually working?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

Im using JS ajax and php for a login and register system for a game im building.

My problem i have is im not sure the ajax request is actually proccessing the php code i have pointed it to. The correct things happen on the webpage when i run the code, but i have put a var_dump() into the php to make sure the data is actually there but i have nothing show up from the php on the webpage as you usually would with var_dump()

Heres the html im using:

```
<article id="container">
    <div id="load-new" class="game_menu">
        <h1>LOAD/NEW</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="reg" class="game_menu">
        <h1>REGISTER</h1>
        <form name="register" method="post" action="">
                <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname">Your username</label>
                <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail"> Your email</label>
                <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="domain@mydomain.com"/>
                <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd">Your password </label>
                <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password"/>
                <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd">Please confirm your password </label>
                <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password"/>
                <button id="reg_submit" type="button">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="login" class="game_menu">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
        <form name="login" method="post" action="">
            <label for="username" id="username_label">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""/>
            <label for="password" id="password_label">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""/>
            <button id="login_submit" type="button">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="access" class="game_menu">
        <h1>ACCESS</h1>
        <button id="login_but" type="button">Login</button>
        <button id="reg_but" type="button">Register</button>
    </div>
```

heres the JS im using with the ajax request:

```
this.login_ajax = function()
{
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&password='+ password;
        alert(dataString);

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"PHP/login.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            $('#login').hide();
            $('#load-new').show();
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("ERROR");
        }

    });
};
```

and here is the php file is runs:

```
 if ((isset($_POST['username'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['username'])) > 0)) {
    $username = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
} else {$username = 'No username entered';}
if ((isset($_POST['password'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) > 0)) {
    $password = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
} else {$password = 'No password entered';}

var_dump($username);
```

Like i said, the ajax request returns successful, but im receiving no dumps from the php file which is making me think, is the php file actually running?

Thanks

Comment: Assign a value to `$username` before your if statements, because if those fail, it will `var_dump()` nothing and you won't know if the script is running or not.

Comment: i just done what you said made %username = hello then var_dumped striaght after and nope it didnt get dumped to screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the php file directly from the browser to check the results. This  is easier if you use GET, at least for development.

And your code does not interact with the info received from the server. The callback should have a parameter

```
success: function (data) {

    alert(data);

}
```

**EDIT**

AJAX activities normally consist of executing a programme in the server (in your case login.php), and retrieving the results (a string). But asking information from the server and doing nothing with it would be pretty stupid, right? So this is why we define a callback function for the success.

Imagine you have a .php file that looks a reference of a book in a database, and prints the name of the author. What you retrieve in the client is the name of the author... so one naive callback function could be:

```
success: function (author) {
    alert('that book was written by ' + author);
}
```

The first parameter of the success callback is the string received from server. In case you want to return multiple values instead of a string, you should use the $.getJSON function, or specify in $.ajax that you want to parse the result as JSON.

Comment: could you expand on this a bit please, im new to using ajax... thanks

Comment: so in order to retun the value from the server what code should i have in the php script? would it be, echo(variable_name)??

Comment: Yes. If it is a simple value you can just `echo $value;` it. If you wanna pass several values, store them into an associative array / object, and then do `echo json_encode($assoc_array);`, telling JS that the input has to be treated as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Within success(), you can check to see the data that is being passed from PHP to your HTML page. You have to setup success function(data) {...}, and do something like console.log(data); within the success function itself. Then open up your browser and see what the console.log is spitting out.

And if you work with Google Chrome - I highly recommend downloading the Chrome plugin [PHP Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/php-console/nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef?hl=en) for checking future PHP errors and warnings.  It may not be perfect but i think it's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

*There is a simpler way to check AJAX requests than checking the result via the AJAX callbacks with console.log*, and you'll be able to see **all** the details of the request/response, including HTTP status codes (so you can see if you're not getting a 500 server error).

- First set up your server-side script (PHP in your case) to dump everything you need to check on. It doesn't matter what format it's in (JSON / XML / plaintext), because we'll be looking at the raw response in a moment.
- Add a button to your HTML and wire it up in jQuery to make the AJAX request on click:

  $('#testButton').click(function(){
      $.ajax(options);
  });

Most browsers now have Developer Tools (Firebug in Firefox?)

On Chrome:

- Press F12 to open the Developer Tools.
- Switch to the Network tab.
- From the moment you open the Network tab, devtools begins recording each request that is made from the page.
- Now initiate your AJAX request (via a test button is usually good), and you should see the request show up in the list.
- When you click on the request it will open up the details, where you can see Headers, Preview, Response, Cookies, and Timing details.

On Internet Explorer:

- Press F12 to open the Developer Tools.
- Switch to the Network tab.
- Press the Start Capturing button
- Initiate your AJAX request
- Double click on the response to see the details

On Firefox:

- I'm sure it's similar, but I haven't used it in a while, so hopefully someone can edit this and add the proper steps!

This will be the best way to look into what exactly is happening behind your AJAX requests.

Don't get me wrong - you can (and should) still use the AJAX callbacks and console.log (or console.dir in Chrome) to debug your AJAX requests, but when things just aren't working, devtools are always the easiest and fastest way to "look under the hood"!

Comment: This helped alot thankyou, i can now see that the data is getting parsed to the php script and being var dumped on the output, why it doesnt show the dump on the main window though i have no idea

Comment: That depends on what ajax function you're using (ajax, post, get, getJSON, load, etc), and the content / data type. I always just send JSON and return JSON to keep it simple, but I don't know whether that's the "best" way or not. It's always nice to see that AJAX is actually "working" for starters! Glad to hear it worked for you.

Comment: I just tried setting datatype to json, but now the ajax is erroring, so i tried sending the data like " data: {username:username,password:password}" instead, but again error, any ideas?

Comment: Don't serialize to JSON yourself. Store all your data in an associative array and then use the `function json_encode();`. And @AaronBlenkush, yeah JSON is the way to go, unless you are passing a raw string, in which case is not worth.

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(object)` to serialize from JavaScript to send to PHP.